# How do I run Unix commands using system and backticks?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, system, command-line-arguments

This works:

```
system("ruby #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test')}")
```

but this

```
`ruby #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test'}`
```

does not run the script Test

And this:

```
system("ruby #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test #{arg}'")
```

does not take the arg value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do backticks mean in the shell you are using.  You don't indicate the shell. (2nd line).  And what is the value of the variable 'arg'?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60. I am trying to run unix commands through a ruby file. `arg` is a word which I will pass through command line. `system("echo #{arg}")` gives the correct value of arg.

Comment: For clarity and to reduce the likelihood of errors, assign your path to a variable, then use that variable for interpolation in the string. Don't do calculations in your interpolation; That's madness.

Comment: It does us no good for you to say "doesn't work". You MUST be specific, otherwise, for every ambiguity you toss out, we have to be less specific in our answers, or we have to waste time trying to figure out what really happens.

Answer (score 3):

The second doesn't work because there's a unbalanced trailing double-quote (`"`) and closing parenthesis (`)`) which is probably raising and error, but you're not seeing it because the back-ticks ignore STDERR:

```
`ruby #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test'")}`
```

The third one doesn't work because you're trying to interpolate a variable into a fixed string enclosed in single-quotes, which is also missing a terminating `}`:

```
system("ruby #{File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test #{arg}'")
```

You'd see this stand out if you *didn't* embed the string calculation in your string interpolation:

```
cmd_file = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/Test #{arg}'
system("ruby #{ cmd_file }")
```

Fixing the quoting and using the intrinsic `File.join` for correctness:

```
cmd_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Test #{arg}")
system("ruby #{ cmd_file }")
```